# XStream: Parsing JSON into a class with a JSONObject field

Tags: java, json, xstream

I need to parse a JSON with XStream, in which one of the classes has a JSONObject field which XStream should just dump the JSON into it directly.  However, XStream (currently using 1.4.1) tries to parse that JSON and fails with an UnknownFieldException.  Here's the isolated code:

```
class Container {
    public JSonObject data = null;
}

public class TestXStreamJson {
    public String testRequest = "{\"container\":{\"data\":{\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\"}}}";

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        XStream xs = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
        xs.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
        xs.alias("container", Container.class);
        Object x = xs.fromXML(testRequest);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

And the resulting stack trace of XStream:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field org.json.JSONObject.FirstName
---- Debugging information ----
field               : FirstName
class               : org.json.JSONObject
required-type       : org.json.JSONObject
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
line number         : -1
class[1]            : com.genesyslab.brs.api.Container
version             : null
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.determineType(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:449)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:290)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:230)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:351)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:302)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:230)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1035)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1019)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:895)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:886)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `new JSonObject(testRequest)` in stead of using XStream?

Comment: The incoming JSON is not wholly parsed into org.json structure.  `Container` class above has other fields to be populated by XStream.  Using `new JSONObject(testRequest)` would build a org.json structure which will need to be processed back into `Container`.

Furthermore, the incoming JSON could be aliased into other classes, not necessarily `Container`.